# Struts2 s:checkbox - unwanted input type hidden

Tags: java, struts2, struts-tags

My code:

```
<label class="btn btn-default">
    <s:checkbox name="viewTypeDescr" />&#32;
    <s:text name="name.contentType" />
</label>
```

The docs: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/checkbox.html
say that it will render a `input[type=checkbox]`

Instead here's what I get:

```
<label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="checkbox" name="viewTypeDescr" value="true" id="search_viewTypeDescr">
    <input type="hidden" id="__checkbox_search_viewTypeDescr" name="__checkbox_viewTypeDescr" value="true"> 
    Content Type
</label>
```

That added `input[type="hidden"]` is making the resulting page invalid because a label can have max 1 input inside.

Definition of invalid:

1. Go to validator.w3.org
2. Paste the provided HTML code in "Validate by direct input"
3. Decor it with missing `<html><head><title>foo</title></head><body>` and `</body></html>` to lessen the false errors
4. Select HTML5 ad doctype
5. Click "Validate"
6. Get this error: "Line xyz, Column abc: The label element may contain at most one input, button, select, textarea, or keygen descendant."
7. Go to spec just in case: "The caption can be associated with a specific form control, known as the label element's labeled control, either using the for attribute, or by putting the form control inside the label element itself."
8. Discover that "If the for attribute is not specified, but the label element has a labelable element descendant, then the first such descendant in tree order is the label element's labeled control."
9. Add that hidden can't be there "http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#category-label"

Anyway, when you submit your document to QA for validation, they use validator.w3.org and that is all that matters.

What's the reason of that hidden? How could I get rid of it or move it elsewhere?

Comment: Are you sure there's a hidden field?

Comment: How do you check the validness of your HTML? Where did you find that label can have only one input? `Each LABEL element is associated with exactly one form control.` `Associated` isn't `can have`.

Comment: Updated with "validation" info

Comment: @RomanC of course there is: see the code in the question? I pasted it from the real scenario.

Comment: @Trumbitta: So just use `for` attribute.

Comment: @AleksandrM I need to use implicit association (checkbox inside the label) to properly render it as a btn-group. Hence why I was asking what's this hidden for, and how do I get rid of it or just move it elsewhere.

Comment: @Trumbitta: The HTML5 in validator.w3.org is experimental. As for the rendering you can wrap label and input with some div.

Comment: @Trumbitta The same way I could ask you why do you need checkbox tag, just use input checkbox and you've done.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new theme, with parent=simple, and will use that.

Still don't know what's the supposed purpose of that hidden...

Comment: The purpose: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/checkbox-interceptor.html.

Comment: The purpose is clear: to submit a value for an unchecked check box. This is a common pattern.

Comment: Agreed. But it should be optional, and opt-in.

Comment: IMO there is no issue here. It could be achieved w/o changing template.